# Static files not available in application when displaying Dropdown (trying to use MaxMenuHeight)

Tags: blazor-webassembly, blazorise

I have an issue where my Blazorise dropdown is extending to the top of the screen, and am trying to use MaxMenuHeight to limit it.

When I look at the example on the blazorise page, I can see that the .dropdown-menu-scrollable css class references the blazorise.bootstrap5.min.css stylesheet, but when I look at my blazor app it doesn't see any css file.

Here is my index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <!--<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="https://s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/tradingreplay.webassets/mss.ico" />
    <title>My Stock Scanner</title>
    <base href="/" />

    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.11.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css">

    <link href="_content/Blazorise/blazorise.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="_content/Blazorise.Bootstrap/blazorise.bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="_content/Blazorise.Snackbar/blazorise.snackbar.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="_content/Blazorise.LoadingIndicator/blazorise.loadingindicator.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="_content/Blazorise.SpinKit/blazorise.spinkit.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <link href="css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/flag-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="TradingReplayClient.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script type="text/javascript"
            src="https://app.termly.io/embed.min.js"
            data-auto-block="on"
            data-website-uuid="7738e3f8-2549-48b2-a597-25a226868c42">
    </script>
</head>
    <body>
        <div id="app">Loading...</div>

        <div id="blazor-error-ui">
            An unhandled error has occurred.
            <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
            <a class="dismiss"></a>
        </div>

        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/annotations.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
        <script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>
        <script src="/scripts.js"></script>
        <script src="_content/Blazorise.Animate/blazorise.animate.js?v=1.2.5.0"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

No answers anywhere for this so I had to roll my own css:

```
.dropdown-menu.dropdown-menu-scrollable {
    max-height: 250px; 
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```